# Value of $\pi$ and algorithm for Bernoulli numbers

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, algorithms, pi, bernoulli-numbers

Chowla and Hartung provide an "algorithm" for computing Bernoulli numbers in this paper (https://www.semanticscholar.org/paper/An-%22exact%22-formula-for-the-m-th-Bernoulli-number-Chowla-Hartung/f094efb657333ac16210f1594c3850bd6712d3bb).

In particular, if the Bernoulli numbers are defined by *(Chowla and Hartung use an obsolete definition of the Bernoulli numbers)*
$$\frac{x}{e^x-1}=1-\frac{x}{2}+\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{n-1}B_n x^{2n}}{(2n)!},$$
then for $m\ge 1$:
$$2(2^{2m}-1)B_m=\lfloor \varphi_m\rfloor +1$$
where
$$\varphi_m=\frac{2(2^{2m}-1)(2m)!}{2^{2m-1}\pi^{2m}}\sum_{n=1}^{3m}\frac{1}{n^{2m}}.$$

There is one problem though. When trying to implement this "algorithm", I realized that I need some sequence of rational approximations to $\pi$. With increasing $m$, I need better and better rational approximations to $\pi$. This is because, for large $m$, $\pi^{2m}$ and $(\pi\pm\varepsilon)^{2m}$ are very different even for small $\varepsilon$.

The question is: To what accuracy do I need to approximate $\pi$ in order for this "algorithm" to work for a given $m$?

This problem is not discussed in the paper at all so I posted this question.

Comment: Presumably if $m\varepsilon \ll 1$ then $(\pi\pm\varepsilon)^{2m} = \pi^{2m} \pm 2m \varepsilon  \pi^{2m-1} + o(\varepsilon)$

Comment: The formulas don't look correct to me since $\frac{x}{e^x-1}=1-\frac{x}{2}+\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{B_{2 n} x^{2 n}}{(2 n)!}$ and it seems that $2 \left(2^{2 m}-1\right) (-1)^{m+1} B_{2 m}=\lfloor \phi(m)\rfloor +1$.

Comment: @StevenClark There's nothing wrong; they are just using an obsolete definition for the Bernoulli numbers. The modern definition is, of course, the one in your comment.

Comment: @StevenClark I'll edit the post to clarify this.